# Accessing struct element straight from function call in C

Tags: c, gcc, struct, c99, c11

I don't fully understand if it's normal to get struct element straight from function call which returns struct (or pointer to struct) like in the following lines of code:

```
function().num
ptr_function(&var)->num
```

Below is code example I wrote which compiles and runs without any issues on my system.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 32

typedef struct
{
  int     num;
  char    str[LEN];
} myType;


myType function( void )
{
  myType var;

  var.num = 10;
  strncpy( var.str, "Hello!", LEN );

  return var;
}

myType* ptr_function( myType* var )
{
  var->num = 20;
  strncpy( var->str, "Hello ptr!", LEN );

  return var;
}

int main()
{
  /* 1st example */
  printf( "%d %s\n", function().num, function().str );

  /* 2nd example */
  myType var;
  printf( "%d %s\n", ptr_function(&var)->num, ptr_function(&var)->str );

  return 0;
}
```

And it returns the following:

```
10 Hello!
20 Hello ptr!
```

So my question is: Are there any issues or undefined behaviour which will arise from doing the following in c99 or c11?

```
function().num
ptr_function(&var)->num
```

Comment: You're evaluating the function multiple times. If there are any side effects that the function has (or it simply alters it argument in a non-straightforward manner), your results may not be what you want. For example, for your second example, initialize `var` outside the function call with e.g. `num = 0`, then in `ptr_function`, use `var->num += 10`, and switch the two variables in the last `printf`, so that `ptr_function(&var)->num` will be  last: it will now (likely) be 20, while if it's the first argument, it would be 10.

Comment: Note to the above: I don't actually know if the evaluation order of arguments inside a function is well defined in C. It may very well not be, in which case you will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your code is perfectly legal.  When returning a pointer, you should always keep in mind whether it's a pointer to an object whose lifetime has not ended, and if it's dynamically allocated, who needs to free it.  In this case it's a pointer to `var` whose lifetime is the enclosing block in `main`, so that's fine, and it isn't dynamically allocated so doesn't need to be freed.

Comment: @00: The order is unspecified.  But that wouldn't make it "undefined behavior" in the usual sense of the C standard: they might be evaluated in one order or the other, but as long as your code is okay with either, you won't get a crash or nasal demons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is technically correct and safe.

Do note that `function()` or `ptr_function(&var)` gets called twice. For some functions, that might not be desirable! And if you had different function calls such as `outer(function1().value, function2().value)`, the order of the two function calls is not specified, so that could cause nasty surprises if they have interacting side effects.

Another possible catch to the pointer version of the pattern: If a function returns a pointer to allocated memory and expects the caller to `free` it, immediately using the return value result means the caller isn't keeping that pointer value and can't actually `free` it later.

[For a case like that, the code could still do:

```
someType *ptr;
outer_func((ptr = allocating_func())->field);
// ...
free(ptr);
```

but this is getting pretty strange and difficult to read. And since you need to declare `ptr` anyway, why not initialize it on the same line?]

This isn't an issue with the given example since the pointer actually points at `var` in `main`, so it doesn't need to be freed and is still valid when the `->` operator is evaluated.